# Problems processing child and parent records via trigger in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have an SQL database that contains a Sales (dbo.Ventas) and SalesDetails (dbo.VentasDetalle) tables in a one to many relationship.
I needed to process newly created and newly updated sales by an external webservice. Therefore I created an auxiliary table Aux and a trigger that would insert the sale id into the aux table along with a 0 for an is_processed value, each time a Sales record is created or updated.

A C# function iterates over the records in the aux table with is_processed value of 0, processes them via the webservice and saves a value of 1 when done.
It does work, and it's supposedly the recommended way to handle my use case. However I have an issue that is throwing a wrench into things.

My INSERT trigger is firing each time a Sales record is created which is ok, but the UPDATE is also firing not only when a Sale table record is updated, but also when any the child records from SalesDetails is created. So for a 16 row sale, I have to process 1 CREATE and 16 UPDATES for Sale table. This does not make much sense, as the Sale Table is not being modified, only the child records are being created.

My triggers are written as follows:

INSERT:

```
USE [Prisma]
GO
/****** Objeto:  Trigger [dbo].[Ventas_INSERT]    Fecha de la secuencia de comandos: 07/06/2017 11:34:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Ventas_INSERT]
       ON [dbo].[Ventas]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @Venta_Id varchar(255), @Tipo_Doc varchar(255)

       SELECT @Venta_Id = INSERTED.Venta_Id, @Tipo_Doc=Tipo_Doc       
       FROM INSERTED

    if(Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='FA' or Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='BO' or Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='NC' or Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='ND')
        begin
            INSERT INTO aux(Venta_Id,source,is_process,action)
            VALUES(@Venta_Id,'VENTAS',0, 'Inserted')
        end

END
```

UPDATE:

```
USE [Prisma]
GO
/****** Objeto:  Trigger [dbo].[Ventas_UPDATE]    Fecha de la secuencia de comandos: 07/06/2017 11:36:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Ventas_UPDATE]
       ON [dbo].[Ventas]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @Venta_Id varchar(255),  @Tipo_Doc varchar(255)

       SELECT @Venta_Id = INSERTED.Venta_Id,  @Tipo_Doc=Tipo_Doc              
       FROM INSERTED

        if(Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='FA' or Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='BO' or Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='NC' or Upper(@Tipo_Doc) ='ND')
        begin
             INSERT INTO aux(Venta_Id,source,is_process,action)
             VALUES(@Venta_Id,'VENTAS',0, 'Update')
        end

END
```

Is there any way to prevent the trigger from firing an UPDATE or filtering them out in the trigger code when only child records are being created?

Comment: Hmm - maybe I need to read up on triggers, but from the looks of this, your update trigger shouldn't fire after inserts.  What am I missing?

Comment: Just to clarify: The UPDATE trigger is firing for Sales (dbo.Ventas) table when a child record is inserted into SalesDetail (dbo.VentasDetalle) table.

Comment: Do you have any other triggers?  Perhaps one on the VentasDetalle table?  This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Nope. Its the only trigger in the whole database. I have read on the internet that this happens when child records of a parent table are created though: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wFvIAI. If it's not the standard behaviour for SQL Server then the stored procedure code that creates the child records may be updating something on the parent record. I can look into it if it's not the default behaviour

Comment: yes, you should definitely look at the code that creates the child records.  That would be my first step in troubleshooting this.

Comment: On top of what @StanShaw said, maybe you can restrict trigger action to updates on certain columns only, via `UPDATE` function.

Comment: Thank you Alex. That is what I ended up doing while I troubleshoot the extra UPDATE triggers. I filter based using an `if UPDATE(my_field)` clause.